# Is there a way to find the Work Item assciated with the changeset

Tags: azure-devops, tfs, tfvc

I have identified a changeset in the Repo History, say #1135, Now I want to find which work item is associated to this changeset.

To find the other way around, it is easy as the work-item lists the changeset asscociated with it.

I googled about it looks like I need to look for [Connections](https://techdocs.broadcom.com/us/en/ca-enterprise-software/agile-development-and-management/rally-platform-ca-agile-central/rally/using/check-status/view-build-status/view-changesets-associated-with-a-work-item.html), but I could not find it in Azure-devops.

Answer (score -1):

The question is tagged with C# so I assume this is about using the API.

The question asks about changesets so I assume this is about TFVC and not git. You can retrieve the work items for a given changeset with the '[Changesets - Get Changeset Work Items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/tfvc/changesets/get-changeset-work-items?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP)' API. The response is an array of [`AssociatedWorkItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/tfvc/changesets/get-changeset-work-items?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP#associatedworkitem) objects.

(For git repos use the '[Commits - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP)' API. The [`GitCommit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP#gitcommit) response object should have a `workItems` field which is an array or URIs.)